# Bind Bindingsource to a list

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, c#-2.0, bindingsource

I have a class like

```
internal class CalculationsDataRelations
{
    public List<CalculationsDataRelation> Relations;
}
```

And trying to bind it to a datagridview using following code

```
   relations = new CalculationsDataRelations();
   bs = new BindingSource(relations, "Relations");
   DgvRelations.DataSource = bs;
```

But I get exception "DataMember property 'Relations' cannot be found on the DataSource."

How to bind datagridview properly?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding has to happen with Properties, but your internal class is only providing a Field.  Also, you haven't instantiated the `List<CalculationsDataRelation>` variable with "new".

Try changing it to something like this:

```
internal class CalculationsDataRelations {
  private List<CalculationsDataRelation> relations = new List<CalculationsDataRelation>();

  public List<CalculationsDataRelation> Relations {
    get { return relations; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I changed. It was typo.